# How to derive a relative path using Ant

Tags: apache-flex, ant, path, mxmlc

I'm using Ant and mxmlc to compile ActionScript classes and MXML into swfs, while maintaining the default organization of a Flex Builder (Flash Builder) project.  Many of my ActionScript classes are in project subdirectories, so my project is organized like the following:

```
MyBigProject
-build-imports.xml
-build.xml

-bin-debug
--src
---flash
---app
----CoolWidget1.swf
---Main.swf
--test

-src
--flash
---app
----build-imports.xml
----build.xml
----CoolWidget1.as
--build-imports.xml
--build.xml
--Main.mxml
-test
```

This directory structure maintains the default directory structure of a Flash Builder project so I can perform push-button builds from the Flash Builder IDE.  I've added the Ant build xml's to this project so I can also build from the command line.  I'm trying to create portable ant build scripts that require the least changes to reuse in other projects.  I have everything like I want except for deriving relative paths.

The build-imports.xml file at the root of the project contains the following:

```
<project name="project.root.imports">
    <dirname property="project.root.dir" file="${ant.file.project.root.imports}"/>
</project>
```

While the sub project folders contain build-imports.xml with the following:

```
<project name="MyBigProject.src.flash.app.imports">
    <import file="../build-imports.xml" />
</project>
```

Notice that sub project build-imports.xml walks up the directory hiearchy till it gets to the root build-imports.xml, and there I set the project.root.dir.

I can then use the ${project.root.dir}/bin-debug to specify where to place my binaries.  The only problem I have, is I do not know how to create the same directory structure as what lies under my src folder.  I need to be able to derive a relative path or perform some string manipulation to create new directorys.

Considering the above information, how do I take a known path like:
${project.root.dir}/src/app
and derive a directory path like:
${project.root.dir}/bin-debug/app

I've found some information about the Ant-contribu propertyregex task, which would allow some string manipulation, but I'm hoping there is an Ant guru out there that can point to a simple solution.  I believe it's highly likely as an Ant novice, I'm simply overlooking the obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My build files have evolved a bit since I posted, but I've resolved the problem.  I believe the following would work correctly in the basic setup previously described:

Add this to the default target in the sub project's build.xml

```
<path id="build.path">
   <pathelement location="." />
</path>
<pathconvert property="build.dir" refid="build.path">
    <map from="${project.root.dir}" to="${project.root.dir}/bin-debug"/>
</pathconvert>
```

Comment: Note that you do not need to define path object first. It would also work to include &lt;path location="."/> as a child to pathconvert instead of refid attribute.

Comment: I dont know what is wrong but above mention piece is not working as per aspectation in linux . In my case it works for windows. Can anyone answer on same ?